# jQuery unable to use Sortable with Isotope

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-isotope

I am trying to make a table of items which will be sortable, using jQuery UI's native `sortable` option, as well as sortable based on certain criteria, using the Isotope plugin ([here)](http://isotope.metafizzy.co).

Here's my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SA5yh/4/. As you will find out, here Isotope works fine, clicking the button indeed sorts it as expected. But the jQuery UI `sortable` does not work, you can drag it, but once released, it returns to its original position. Without `isotope` use, it works fine, as expected: http://jsfiddle.net/SA5yh/5/. Any idea how do I make both work?

Comment: booth plugins works fine BUT isotope doesnt change the div order in the DOM! 
Isotope only defines absolute positions and sortable reorder the DOM. If you try to sort after init Isotope you change the position inside DOM but the absolute position from Isotope doesnt change.

Comment: is it necessary to use isotope? you also can sort your divs with jquery sort

Comment: The problem is the styling applied by isotope. You can leverage isotope animations and the order it computes to actually move around the elements so that the styling won't be needed anymore: at that point, you will be able to drag and drop elements again.
See answer below and jsfiddle example for details

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Isotope adds a style attibute with position restrictions, as mentioned in another answer as well.

Here it is the cure:
http://jsfiddle.net/zd6mT/4/

```
  //An event handler for when isotope is done reordering elements
  $container.isotope( 'on', 'layoutComplete',
      function( isoInstance, laidOutItems ) {

          var n = laidOutItems.length;
          for (var i = n-1; i >= 0; i--) {
              //Starting from the last element in the list
              //moves them to the beginning of their parent tag
              //so in the end the elements are actually sorted
              //and style properties can be removed
              $('.test').prepend(laidOutItems[i].element);
          }
          //remove all styles applied by isotope
          $('.bookmark').removeAttr('style');
          $container.isotope('destroy');
      }
  );
```

Basically you can use the sorted list generated by isotope to actually perform the sorting of the children elements as jQuery UI sortable would do.

Once they are all in place, you don't need the styling constraints that isotope had forced.

So once the animation by isotope is over, you first sort all the children, and then strip them from the style attrbute (assuming you had not added anything else directly to the elements, of course - otherwise, just strip the `position:absolute` css rule inside the style attribute)

**EDIT**  we must also destroy the isotope object after every reordering, otherwise it will mess-up

Answer (score 2):

It does seem that there is a conflict with isotope. Placing the container variable declaration inside of the click allows me to use sortable until I do invoke the .click on the "foo" button.

[Initially working sort jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SA5yh/6/)

I'm pretty sure this is due to the style that isotope is applying after the click. The absolute position is fixing these div to these positions if you see below. This absolute position will not allow these elements to take on a new position. You would need to write over this position on the jquery drop event if you wish to continue this route.

Initial HTML on load:

```
<div class="test test2 ui-sortable">
            <div class="bookmark b1">z</div>
            <div class="bookmark b2">d</div>
            <div class="bookmark b3">s</div>
            <div class="bookmark b4">a</div>
            <div class="bookmark b5">q</div>
            <div class="bookmark b6">e</div>
            <div class="bookmark b7">b</div>
</div>
```

And HTML after "foo" click:

```
<div class="test test2 ui-sortable" style="position: relative; height: 350px;">     
    <div class="bookmark b1" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 300px;"></div>
    <div class="bookmark b2" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 100px;">d</div>
    <div class="bookmark b3" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 250px;">s</div>
    <div class="bookmark b4" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;">a</div>
    <div class="bookmark b5" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 200px;">q</div>
    <div class="bookmark b6" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 150px;">e</div>
    <div class="bookmark b7" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 50px;">b</div>
</div>
```